# Integral of $\frac1x$

Tags: integration, derivatives

When integrating $\frac1x$, you would get $\ln|x|+c$. Working under that assumption, any given derivative of $\ln|ax|+c$ would give you the same answer as any derivative of $\ln|x|+c$.  Given this, after deriving and then integrating, $\ln|2x|+c$ and $\ln|100x|+c$ would have the same solutions of $\frac1x$ after integrating and $\ln|x|+c$, even though the two original equations have differing solutions, the resulting equation are identical. Is there a way to differentiate the equations even after deriving and integrating?  Are the solutions found after this process incorrect?

Comment: What's the question?  Yes, indefinite integrals are only defined up to an additive constant.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I'm not sure just what you're asking - but you may be able to answer your own question if you realize that $\ln(ax) = \ln(a) +  \ln(x)$ so it's just $\ln(x)$ + a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct. Note that $\ln(ax) = \ln a + \ln x$. So, working backwards, we have
$$\ln x + C = \ln x + \ln (e^C) = \ln(e^Cx)$$
This is why $\ln x, \ln 2x, \ln 100x$, etc., behave similarly.

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln|ax|+C = \ln|a| + \ln|x| + C = \ln|x| + C$$
Note that $\ln|a|$ is constant, so we can simply wrap it into $C$